# Query Data from 2 MySQL tables with some duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that track rewards points. One is a summary table and one is a detail table. When a transaction (addition or subtraction of reward points)happens an entry is suppose to be written to both tables Unfortunately we found through a scripting error that sometimes an entry was only written to one table.

So now I need to query the database to list the transactions, without repeating the duplicates. There are not matching IDs in the table, however the DateSubmitted is a timestamp and all matching records between the 2 table share the same timestamp.

So, I have 2 queries

```
SELECT CustID, DateSubmitted, Type, Points
FROM `trans_summary`
WHERE CustID = '10009'
```

and

```
SELECT CustID, DateSubmitted, Type, PointTotal as Points
FROM `ptrans_detail` 
WHERE CustID = '10009'
  and DateSubmitted NOT IN 
        (SELECT DateSubmitted FROM `trans_summary` 
         WHERE CustID = '10009'
        )
```

How can I combine these 2 queries to get one output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use union if you need distinct result for both or union all if need  also duplicated result

```
      SELECT CustID
          , DateSubmitted
          , Type
          , Points
              FROM `trans_summary`
                WHERE CustID = '10009'
    UNION

    SELECT CustID
    , DateSubmitted
    , Type
    , PointTotal 
        FROM `ptrans_detail` 
           WHERE CustID = '10009'
                and DateSubmitted NOT IN 
               (SELECT DateSubmitted FROM 
                 `trans_summary` 
                  WHERE CustID = '10009')
```

or union all if need also duplicated result

```
      SELECT CustID
          , DateSubmitted
          , Type
          , Points
              FROM `trans_summary`
                WHERE CustID = '10009'
    UNION ALL 

    SELECT CustID
    , DateSubmitted
    , Type
    , PointTotal 
        FROM `ptrans_detail` 
           WHERE CustID = '10009'
                and DateSubmitted NOT IN 
               (SELECT DateSubmitted FROM 
                 `trans_summary` 
                  WHERE CustID = '10009')
```

Comment: Thank You! That worked! When we thought we had all the data in one table I originally had a running total by using `( SELECT SUM( PointTotal ) 
     FROM ptrans_detail x 
    WHERE x.CustID = a.CustID
    AND ( x.DateSubmitted < a.DateSubmitted OR x.DateSubmitted = a.DateSubmitted) ) AS RunningTotal ` 
Is it possible to do this with the union as well?

Comment: Looking at you new code in comment i can't understand  your new ( or your extended) question (is not easy undestand the context you mean) 
.. so please for this new question provide a new well described  and documented question in a new post ..

eventually when you have posted  the new question comment me the related  link

Comment: Thank you. The link to the new question is [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914557/create-a-running-balance-total-on-query-with-union)