# Create a Running Balance Total on Query with Union

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a webapp that tracks rewards points for customers. We are using a MySQL database.
I originally had a query that pulled data from a single table and showed the amount of points in each transaction along with the balance (RunningTotal) the code is below:

```
SELECT DateSubmitted
, PointTotal as Points
,   ( SELECT SUM( PointTotal ) 
        FROM ptrans_detail x 
            WHERE x.CustID = a.CustID
            AND ( x.DateSubmitted < a.DateSubmitted OR x.DateSubmitted = a.DateSubmitted) ) AS RunningTotal 
, comment 
   FROM ptrans_detail a 
    WHERE CustID='10009' 
    Order by TransID Desc
```

This worked fine until it was discovered that there were some entries that didn't exists in the ptrans_detail table and that question was posted here:
[Query Data from 2 MySQL tables with some duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897394/query-data-from-2-mysql-tables-with-some-duplicate-records/40897585)

As suggested, I used UNION to combine 2 queries from 2 tables to get ALL the records, that query is:

```
SELECT CustID
      , DateSubmitted
      , Type
      , Points
          FROM `trans_summary`
            WHERE CustID = '10009'
UNION

SELECT CustID
, DateSubmitted
, Type
, PointTotal 
    FROM `ptrans_detail` 
       WHERE CustID = '10009'
            and DateSubmitted NOT IN 
           (SELECT DateSubmitted FROM 
             `trans_summary` 
              WHERE CustID = '10009')
```

That worked great but now I would like to add the RunningTotal to this like in the first query. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, consider this whole statements as a subquery and do the running total outside of that SELECT * FROM (your union query here). Also, mysql and sql server are different databases, which are you using?

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
SELECT CustID, DateSubmitted, Type, SUM(Points) FROM (SELECT CustID
          , DateSubmitted
          , Type
          , Points
              FROM `trans_summary`
                WHERE CustID = '10009'
    UNION

    SELECT CustID
    , DateSubmitted
    , Type
    , PointTotal as Points
        FROM `ptrans_detail` 
           WHERE CustID = '10009'
                and DateSubmitted NOT IN 
               (SELECT DateSubmitted FROM 
                 `trans_summary` 
                  WHERE CustID = '10009')) AS tr_summery
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `union all`, unless you really need `union`.

The easiest way to get a running sum in MySQL is to use variables:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (@sump := if(@c = CustId, @sump + Points,
                    if(@c := CustId, Points, Points)
                   )
       ) as runningTotal
FROM (SELECT CustID, DateSubmitted, Type, Points
      FROM trans_summary
      WHERE CustID = '10009'
      UNION ALL   -- Maybe it should be `UNION`
      SELECT CustID, DateSubmitted, Type, PointTotal 
      FROM ptrans_detail 
      WHERE CustID = '10009' AND
            DateSubmitted NOT IN (SELECT ts.DateSubmitted FROM trans_summary ts WHERE ts.CustID = '10009')
    ) t CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @c := -1, @sump := 0) params
ORDER BY CustId, DateSubmitted;
```

Comment: Well, some of the records are duplicated in both tables, so I only wanted to show those once, I was under the impression that was achieved by using UNION over UNION ALL

Comment: Works great. My only issue is that I want to display by DateSubmitted Desc (Newest records first). However the running total is starting on the most recent date and totaling up going back... How can I reverse that so it totals from the oldest DataSubmitted going forward?

Comment: Does `ORDER BY CustId, DateSubmitted DESC` solve the problem?